# No administrative CSS for arabic language

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual website with English, French, and Arabic; I updated from Drupal 7.22 to 7.23 and I found that I don't have the CSS for the homepage in Arabic, as the image below.

[image]

Why is it happening? How can I fix this?

#### Notes

I'm aggregating and using Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation advagg.  I'm using Boost module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i find the solution: i emptied all the cache tables manually in the database and it's ok

Answer (score 0):

By default, many themes have a separate RTL template or CSS. Depending on what theme you are using, you may have to create RTL CSS or change the behavior of which CSS files it's looking for. Try searching for a *-rtl.css file (where * is some name that comes before the suffix.)

Comment: I'm using SimpleCorp theme, the problem is everything goes wright before

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "everything goes wright before." Does your theme have a -rtl.css file or any special rtl (right-to-left) handling?

Comment: @beth I guess he means "Everything was right, before." I take the problem is recent, and the site worked fine, before.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes that what i meaned,the problem happened just after upgrading to drupal7.23